# How can I count access to a file from Apache access logs using Bash

Tags: apache, bash, logging

I have a `/redir` directory on a website where a `.htaccess` file redirects various static addresses to other addresses for the purposes of counting the number of times a particular link is accessed.  I want to write a script to help count that data.

I already have two scripts in place. The first appends data to a log.total file from the `access.log.0` file at about 2:00 AM daily via a cron job.  The second is a script that can be run interactively to run generate the counts, given a minimum and maximum date.

The cron script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f log.tmp
grep "GET /redir/.*" access.log.0 | cut -d " " -f4,5,7 > log.tmp
cat log.tmp >> log.total
rm log.tmp
```

This generates data that looks like:

```
[21/Aug/2012:00:31:27 -0700] /redir/abc.html
[21/Aug/2012:00:31:35 -0700] /redir/def.html
[21/Aug/2012:00:31:35 -0700] /redir/abc.html
[21/Aug/2012:00:31:40 -0700] /redir/ghi.html
[21/Aug/2012:00:31:46 -0700] /redir/123.html
[21/Aug/2012:00:31:58 -0700] /redir/def.html
[21/Aug/2012:00:32:07 -0700] /redir/abc.html
etc...
```

Now, I want a script that I can run using `readLogs.sh "log.total" "1 week ago" "today"` which will count the number of times each file is accessed between one week ago and today.

I've posted my script below which does the job, but there are some limitations, which are outlined there.  The output can be in any readable format.

Comment: Why do you have a temporary `log.tmp`? You could just as well append directly to `log.total`.

Comment: I plan on at some point doing something else with log.tmp, like also appending it to a log.daily or log.weekly, etc.

Comment: Try with `tee`, as in `awk '/GET \/redir\//{ print $4, $5, $7 }'  access.log.0 | tee -a log.total >>log.weekly`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you convert the dates to UNIX timestamps for the range comparisons. You could add them as a second field to your file:

```
[21/Aug/2012:00:31:27 -0700] 1345534287 /redir/abc.html
```

(You can get the UNIX timestamp using `date +%s --date "date string"`. I assume you would like to keep the human readable timestamp, but you could replace it with the timestamp if you want.)

Here's a modified script that assumes your log file is modified as suggested; the script also uses bash parameter expansion to make it a bit shorter:

[Update: modified to exit once the ending timestamp is reached.]

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# :- means to use the RHS if the LHS is null or unset
FILE="${1:-log.total}"  
MINTIME="${2:-1 day ago}"
MAXTIME="${3:-now}"

START=$( date +%s --date "$MINTIME" )
END=$( date +%s --date "$MAXTIME" )

# No need for cut; just have awk print only the field you want
# Field 1 is the date/time
# Field 2 is the timezone
# Field 3 is the timestamp you added
# Field 4 is the path
awk -v start=$START -v end=$END '$3 > end { exit } $3 >= start {print $4}' "$FILE" | \
  sort | uniq -c | sort
```

Comment: Since the values are guaranteed to be in chronological order, is there a way to stop processing once `$3 > end`?

Comment: See the update; exit if '$3' is too big; otherwise, check $3 against start.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script I came up with.  The limitations are that if a date entered does not appear in the logs, it doesn't work properly.  For example, if I enter "1 day ago" as the start date but there were no accesses from yesterday, it will choose the beginning of the file as where to start counting.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" ]; then
FILE="$1"
else
FILE="log.total"
fi

#if test -t 0; then
#INPUT=`cat $FILE`
#else
#INPUT="$(cat -)"
#fi

if [ "$2" ]; then
MINTIME="$2"
else
MINTIME="1 day ago"
fi

if [ "$3" ]; then
MAXTIME="$3"
else
MAXTIME="now"
fi

START=`grep -m 1 -n $(date --date="$MINTIME" +%d/%b/%Y) "$FILE" | cut -d: -f1`
if [ -z "$START" ]; then
START=0
fi

END=`grep -m 1 -n $(date --date="$MAXTIME" +%d/%b/%Y) "$FILE" | cut -d: -f1`
if [ -z "$END" ]; then
END=`wc "$FILE" | cut -d" " -f3`
fi

awk "NR>=$START && NR<$END {print}" "$FILE" | cut -d" " -f3 | sort | uniq -c | sort
```

The output looks like this:

```
    1 /redir/123.html
    1 /redir/ghi.html
    2 /redir/def.html
    3 /redir/abc.html
```